# How do I use ContentProvider to handle the actual reading and writing of data to the filesystem?

Tags: java, android, filesystems, android-contentprovider

I'm trying to develop a program that can make data that isn't actually in a file stored on the device seem like **it is a file stored on the device**. I get the impression that part of ContentProvider I need to tweak to suit my ends is the openFile command. Of course, openFile spawns a ParcelFileDescriptor. This is where I hit a wall, because I can't find any commands in ParcelFileDescriptor that either receive or return bytes or byte arrays or file data.

For example, say I wanted to create an app that ran in the background and tricked my default Android file explorer into thinking that there was a file called "Phantom.txt" in my 'Documents' folder, even though no such file actually exists in the storage space. Then, when the user opens this non-existent file, the background app supplies the data is supposedly contains (but obviously can't contain because it doesn't even exist). The code for this app will have to include code along these lines:

```
public class myContentProvider extends ContentProvider {

    public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(Uri uri, String mode) {
        if(uri.toString()=="file:\\\\Documents\\Phantom.txt") {
            return new myPFD();
        } else {
            return super.openFile(uri, mode);
        }
    }
}

public class myPFD extends ParcelFileDescriptor {

    private final String filedata = "This file doesn't really exist!\nThis text is actually part of an application!\nIt isn't saved to your flash memory!\nWeird, isn't it?";
    private int readPosition;

    public myPFD() {
        super(ParcelFileDescriptor.open(File.createTempFile("uselessParameterFiller", ".tmp"), ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY));
        readPosition = 0;
    }

    //NOTE: There is no actual read(byte [] b) command in ParcelFileDescriptor,
    //But this illustrates the kind of functionality I'm looking to achieve.
    //I just need to replace the nonexistant ParcelFileDescriptor.read(byte [] b)
    //with whatever Android actually uses to read the actual data of the file.

    public int read(byte [] b) {
        byte [] dataAsBytes = filedata.getBytes();
        if(readPosition<dataAsBytes.length) {
            int x = readPosition;
            for(x=readPosition;x<Math.min(readPosition + b.length, dataAsBytes.length);x++){
                b[x - readPosition] = dataAsBytes[x];
            }
            int output = x - readPosition;
            readPosition = x;
            return output;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    //For simplicity's sake, I have forgone writing customizations of other reading
    //commands such as "int read()", and "int read(byte [], int, int)". Also the
    //command "seek(long)", for assigning a reading position.
    //I have also neglected to show any commands that would allow me to recieve and
    //handle any data that an external app might try to write to this nonexistant
    //file. Though I would also like to know how to do this.
}
```